# Sql server- joining with a temp table does not return the right values

Tags: sql-server, join

I am not sure why my query isn't returning the right values when I join a temp table with an actual table. I am using SQL Server 2008 as my database.

**I have the below query**

```
WITH TradeHistory AS (  
  SELECT   
   tran_num,   
   version_number,  
   row_creation AS last_update,  
   tran_status,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tran_num ORDER BY tran_num DESC, row_creation DESC, version_number DESC) AS RowNum  
  FROM tran_history_view (NOLOCK)  
  where   
   row_creation BETWEEN  '2018-01-22 17:02:47.083' AND '2019-01-23 19:02:47.083'   
   AND tran_status IN (3,5)  
   AND update_type NOT IN (15,52,24) 
   AND deal_tracking_num= 10738416 
 )     
   select ab.tran_num as ab_tran_num, ab.version_number as ab_version_num, hist.version_number as hist_version_num, ab.deal_tracking_num as ab_track_num, 
   ab.tran_status as ab_tran_status, hist.tran_status as hist_tran_status from
   TradeHistory hist join  ab_tran ab on ab.tran_num = hist.tran_num
   and hist.RowNum =1
```

I am not sure why my join does not pick the matching row for tran_num and version_num? I get a different version_number and tran_status from tran_history table. If I join on version_number across the two tables, I don't get any rows (as expected based on the values in the final output).

My **'TradeHistory'** temp table returns the below values

```
+----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------+
| tran_num | version_number |       last_update       | tran_status | RowNum |
+----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------+
| 10738416 |              2 | 2019-01-23 16:02:09.760 |           3 |      1 |
| 10738416 |              1 | 2019-01-23 16:01:51.803 |           3 |      2 |
| 10738422 |              4 | 2019-01-23 16:02:30.600 |           3 |      1 |
| 10738422 |              3 | 2019-01-23 16:02:30.243 |           3 |      2 |
| 10738422 |              2 | 2019-01-23 16:02:09.973 |           3 |      3 |
+----------+----------------+-------------------------+-------------+--------+
```

Result of output joining the select query with the temp table is as below. **The version_number and tran_number from the two tables are different and I don't understand why? Can someone please explain?**

```
+---------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+
| hist_tran_num | ab_tran_num | ab_version_num | hist_ver_num | ab_track_num | ab_tran_status | hist_tran_status |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+
|      10738416 |    10738416 |              4 |            2 |     10738416 |             10 |                3 |
|      10738422 |    10738422 |              6 |            4 |     10738416 |             10 |                3 |
+---------------+-------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Your results do not show history trans number.  Since you are doing an inner join on that field they have to be the same.  Nothing in your query looks like it would skew that behavior.  However if you have duplicate tran numbers in either dataset it might provide confusing results.  Also nothing in your query garuntees that the history table version number will match that from the cte.

Comment: For anyone here to give a definitive answer more sample data and other details are needed.  For example what is the code behind the tran_history_view.

Comment: Analyze the result set returned from - 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tran_num ORDER BY tran_num DESC, row_creation DESC, version_number DESC) AS RowNum. You might get some clue as to why the result is not as per your expectations

Comment: @JoeC - I have added 'TradeHistory' table output, please let me know if that helps or if you need to know the trade_history_view table? I have added the hist_tran_num as requested.

Comment: @Dheerendra - The output of the whole query with ROWNUM is the 'TradeHistory' table attached in the OP.

Comment: The actual table you are joining is ab_tran. We have no clue of the data residing in that table. Can you check the version values from the table ab_tran and see if they are same?